# Load data from csv in airflow docker container to snowflake DB

Tags: python, docker, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, airflow

I am running airflow in docker. I have an Extract task that extracts data from some API and stores it to a csv file in my docker container (path is `/opt/airflow/raw/data.csv`

I need to add a load task in my DAG to load the data from the csv file in docker container to a snowflake table. The code for my dag task is

```
from airflow import DAG
from airflow.providers.snowflake.operators.snowflake import SnowflakeOperator

load_task = SnowflakeOperator(
        task_id='load_to_snowflake',
        snowflake_conn_id='snowflake_conn',
        sql=f"""
        COPY INTO rates
        FROM 'file:///opt/airflow/raw/data.csv'
        FILE_FORMAT=(TYPE=CSV SKIP_HEADER=1)
        """,
        autocommit=True,
)
```

I get error that the url `file:///opt/airflow/raw/data.csv` is invalid. Please any ideas?

Comment: You can only use COPY INTO if your data is in an internal/external stage. So you would need to get your files into an internal stage or a cloud location against which you can create an external stage